# Proof Verification: Problem 6, Section 2.5, Intro to Real Analysis, 4th Ed, Bartle

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Could somebody take a look and tell me what they think of my proof [here in PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwz4SrnzmWXzZGV5b1YzS0xOX00/edit?usp=sharing)?

Bartle. Problem 6, Section 2.5, *Intro to Real Analysis*, 4th Ed. p. 52.

> 6. If $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq · · · \supseteq I_n  \supseteq  · · ·  $ is a nested sequence of intervals and if $In = [a_n, b_n]$ , show that
>    $a_1 \le a_2 \le · · · \le a_n $ and $b_1 \ge b_2 \ge · · · \ge b_n \ge   · · · $.

Answer (score 0):

Your link's broken. I don't see a PDF. Can you MathJax or picture your work?

Bartle's partial solution to exercise 6 relies on exercise 1.

p 52. Exercise 1.

> 1. If $I := [a, b]$ and $I' := [a' , b']$ are closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, show that $I \subseteq I'$ if and only if $a' \le a$ and
>    $b' \le b$.

Partial Solution

> 1. Note that $[a, b] ⊆ [a', b']$ if and only if $a' ≤a≤b≤b'$.

Partial Solution to your exercise 6.

> 6. Since $[a_n, b_n]=I_n ⊇ I_{n+1} =[a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}]$, it follows as in Exercise 1 [above] that
>    $a_n ≤a_{n+1} ≤b_{n+1} ≤b_n$. Therefore we have $a_1 ≤a_2≤ · · · ≤a_n≤ · · ·$ and
>    $b_1 ≥b_2≥ · · · ≥b_n≥ · · ·$ .